# excel multiply by % cell that contains numbers and text

Tags: excel, text, numbers, character

Does anyone know if it's even possible and if it's possible how could it be done within excel:

I would like to have cell A1 containing 50 ac (80 bd) be multiplied in cell B1 by 20% so cell B1 would be 60 ac (96 bd). So 2 different numbers from one cell multiplied separately and copying the letters and characters () to one single cell. Could it be done? and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes there is a space character between the number and string, and the brackets are around the second number/string pair

=LEFT(A1,(FIND(" ",A1)))*120% & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND("(",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)+1)& MID(A1,1+FIND("(",A1),FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND("(",A1))-FIND("(",A1))*120% & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND("(",A1)),LEN(A1))

[image: Picture added for clarity]

Comment: You need to get 120% of 80, as well.

Comment: Fixed the answer, given Chuff's comment above

Comment: You also forgot the last part: `MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND("(",A1)),100)` (with reasonable assumption that the last part is equal to or less than 100 characters long).

Comment: fixed - excel didn't pick up the second line from the formula in the copy paste.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I've tried to add the formula to B1, but it doesn't work? gives an error that the formula isn't right

Comment: What result does it give ? It is dependant on the first " " and the first "(" . Try it in B1 with Cell A1 as "50 ab (60 bc)"

Comment: Still showing the error "The formula you have typed contains an error" Is it working in your excel?

Comment: I've added a picture for clarity. Works for me.

Comment: @Wild138 it's working!! THANK YOU. The whole problem was in my non-english version of Excel, I've translated the formula and it's rocking. Sweet! I wanted to ask you about one more thing though. Do you think it would be possible to add a round up function to this formula? So if it the outcome of one of those numbers would be 70,8 it would be come 71 or if it would be 70,2 it would be 70

Comment: =ROUND(LEFT(A1,(FIND(" ",A1)))*120%,0) & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),FIND("(",A1)-FIND(" ",A1)+1)& ROUND(MID(A1,1+FIND("(",A1),FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND("(",A1))-FIND("(",A1))*120%,0) & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1+FIND("(",A1)),LEN(A1))